# angular data binding not working on elements added with d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax, d3.js

I'm trying to make a bubblemap using d3.js and an external json file. I use angular to show/hide bubbles based on checkboxes.

This is the code for my checkboxes:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'pascalprecht.translate']);
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$translate', '$scope', function ($translate, $scope) {
    $scope.wifiCheckbox = true;
    $scope.bluetoothCheckbox = true;
    $scope.jpurseCheckbox = true;
}
```

My html looks something like this:

```
<html id="myAppHtml"  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<head>
    //heading stuff
</head>
<body>

    <div id="bubblemap">
    </div>


    <div id="checkboxGroup">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input ng-model="wifiCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="">{{"CHECKBOX1"| translate}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input ng-model="bluetoothCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="">{{"CHECKBOX2"| translate}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input ng-model="jpurseCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="">{{"CHECKBOX3"| translate}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is where i make the bubblemap:

```
var bubbleData = {};

bubbleData.svg = d3.select("#grondplan")
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', "800px")
        .attr('height', "550px");






bubbleData.setData = function (data) {
    bubbleData.data = data;

    bubbleData.readXML();
    bubbleData.doTheRest();
};

//ajax call to the data
getDataPerSensor(bubbleData.setData);


//reads the svg file containing an image of the map
bubbleData.readXML = function () {
    d3.xml("images/FloorplanScanners.svg", function (error, xml) {
        if (error)
            throw error;
        var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
        var clone = importedNode.cloneNode(true);
        document.querySelector("svg").prepend(clone);
    });
};

//make the circles according to the data
bubbleData.doTheRest = function () {
    bubbleData.maxRadius = d3.max(bubbleData.data, function (d) {
        return d.visitors;
    });
    var circleGroups = bubbleData.svg.selectAll('.circleGroup')
            .data(bubbleData.data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", function (d) {
                return "circleGroup " + d.type;
            })
            .attr("fill", "#d40000")
            .attr("ng-show", function (d) {
                return d.type + "Checkbox";
            });

    var circles = circleGroups.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                return d.cx;
            })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return d.cy;
            })
            .attr("r", 50)
            .attr("id", function (d) {
                return d.location;
            })
            .attr("fill-opacity", 0.5);

    var texts = circleGroups.append("text")

            .attr("id", function (d) {
                return d.locatie + "text";
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return d.cx;
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return d.cy;
            })
            .attr("stroke", "#000000")
            .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
            .attr("dy", ".3em")
            .text("{{ 'WEBSITETITLE' | translate }}");

};
```

I made this map with some dummydata I had at the top of the javascriptfile and everything worked fine. Now however we access the data through an ajax call (which in a later stage will call to a different server).

```
function getDataPerSensor(callback) {
 $.getJSON("../../json/dataPerSensor.json", function(json){
    callback(json);
          });
}
```

I now have the following problem: data binding on the text/circle/g elements created by the doTheRest() function doesn't work. the ng-show is connected correctly, but the groups don't hide when the checkboxes are ticked. I changed the last line in the code to test if the translation works, but seems to fail as well. I've added some pictures of the results.

[image: bubble error]

[image: resulting html]

As you can see the elements are added correctly with the correct attributes, it appears that angular just doesn't connect them properly. the weird thing is that everything else works fine. All the translations work and when i changed the labels next to the checkboxes to show the current state of the checkbox they were also correct.

```
<div id="checkboxGroup" class="bg-white">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input ng-model="wifiCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="">{{wifiCheckbox}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input ng-model="bluetoothCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="">{{bluetoothCheckbox}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input ng-model="jpurseCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="">{{jpurseCheckbox}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

(I can't post an image, only 2 links allowed until I have 10 reputation)

Once again: everything worked perfectly until I changed the data to be received via ajax call. I believe that, because it takes a bit of time to get the data, the elements are added after the page finishes loading and that somehow causes the engular binding to fail. I have not found a solution for this however.

Could anyone help me please?

Thank you very much

EDIT: sorry for the late response, ran out of time and had some trouble making the fiddle. It is finally here: https://jsfiddle.net/3b03gfrr/18/

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: Please create a fiddle or plunkr in order to be easier to help you thanks

Comment: @pedromarce, I have finally added the jsfiddle
I forgot that I use both angular and Jquery, i was warned that this is a bad practice, but the overarching website uses functionality from both. Could the problem be related to this?

Comment: @acostela, I have added the jsfiddle